# Solve $x=d^{d}\log(d)$ using Lambert $W(x)$

Tags: lambert-w, tetration

We have $a=b^b$, so
$$\log(a)=b\log(b)$$
$$x=\frac{x}{W(x)}\log\left(\frac{x}{W(x)}\right)$$
$$b=\frac{\log(a)}{W(\log(a))}$$
Next we have $c=d^{(d^{d})}$, so
$$\log(c)=d^{d}\log(d)$$
In general $^{k}m=n$,
$$^{k-1}m\log(m)=\log(n)$$
Is there a way to solve it as $m=f_{k}(n)$ using Lambert $W(x)$?

Comment: These are called [super-roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Inverse_operations) and do not have closed forms using the Lambert W function.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, thank you for comment! How do you came to my question?

Comment: I've discussed this a bit, finding some generalization of the Lambert-W. See http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/Wexzal_Superroot.pdf

Comment: See this [super root post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314712/calculating-the-nth-super-root-when-n-is-greater-than-2/4697772#4697772)